# How to use Devextreme Angular File uploader without uploading data to server

Tags: angular, devextreme, devextreme-angular

I would like to use Devextreme angular's file uploader component to parse some data in javascript, but I can't seem to find a way, not to post data first to server.

I can parse data in javascript using xlsx library and html `input` tag and its `change` event:

```html
<input type='file' (change)="onSelectFile($event)" multiple>
```

and .ts:

```js
onSelectFile(event) {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      const filesAmount = event.target.files.length;
      for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
        const reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = (event:any) => {

          const bstr: string = event.target.result;
          const data = <any[]>this.excelService.importFromFile(bstr);
          // data is ready
        };
        reader.readAsBinaryString(event.target.files[i]);
      }
    }
  }
```

Can I prevent file-uploader to upload data to server, so I can parse it first on client side?
I would like to use this component, because it provides validations and correct styling out of the box.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try.

```
<dx-file-uploader
  selectButtonText="Upload File"
  labelText="or Drop here"
  accept="*"
  uploadMode="useForm"
  [allowCanceling]="true"
  (change)="handleInputChange($event)"
></dx-file-uploader>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the 'useForm' value of the [uploadMode](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxFileUploader/Configuration/#uploadMode) option but not submit the form.

Comment: Could you describe how this would be done? I've tried doing this, but I can't seem to find a way. Or provide working example?